# JAVA app on voice calling

Tags: java, sockets

I am trying to develop a java app on voice call. the server side relays back the message to all the clients connected to it. Now the problem is even the client who has sent the message originally gets to hear his message back as the server relays the message back to all the clients due which we hear our own voice too. could any help me through this?

my server side code:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Echo
 {                     
       public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception

        {
             ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(3000);
             while(true){Thread echoThread = new Thread(new EchoThread(serverSocket.accept()));
                echoThread.start();}
         }
 }

 class EchoThread implements Runnable
  {
    public static Collection<socket> sockets = new ArrayList<socket>();
    Socket connection = null;
DataInputStream dataIn = null;
DataOutputStream dataOut = null;

public EchoThread(Socket conn) throws Exception
{
    connection = conn;
    dataIn = new DataInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
    dataOut = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
    sockets.add(connection);
}

public void run()
{
    int bytesRead = 0;
    byte[] inBytes = new byte[1];
    while(bytesRead != -1)
    {
        try{bytesRead = dataIn.read(inBytes, 0, inBytes.length);}catch (IOException e)       {}
        if(bytesRead >= 0)
        {
            sendToAll(inBytes, bytesRead);
        }
    }
    sockets.remove(connection);
}

public static void sendToAll(byte[] byteArray, int q)
{
    Iterator<socket> sockIt = sockets.iterator();
    while(sockIt.hasNext())
    {
        Socket temp = sockIt.next();
        DataOutputStream tempOut = null;
        try
        {
            tempOut = new DataOutputStream(temp.getOutputStream());
        } catch (IOException e1)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try{tempOut.write(byteArray, 0, q);}catch (IOException e){}
      }
  }
 }
```

Client side:

Client side:
here i have two classes. one takes microphone input, sends it to the server, and another takes data from the server, and plays that data out of a speaker.

```
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.net.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

 public class Program
{
  public final static String SERVER = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter server    ip");
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    AudioFormat af = new AudioFormat(8000.0f,8,1,true,false);
    DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, af);
    TargetDataLine microphone = (TargetDataLine)AudioSystem.getLine(info);
    microphone.open(af);
    Socket conn = new Socket(SERVER,3000);
    microphone.start();
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
    int bytesRead = 0;
    byte[] soundData = new byte[1];
    Thread inThread = new Thread(new SoundReceiver(conn));
    inThread.start();
    while(bytesRead != -1)
    {
        bytesRead = microphone.read(soundData, 0, soundData.length);
        if(bytesRead >= 0)
        {
            dos.write(soundData, 0, bytesRead);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("IT IS DONE.");
  }
}
```

the sound receiver class :

```
 import java.net.*;
 import java.io.*;

 import javax.sound.sampled.*;

 public class SoundReceiver implements Runnable
 {
 Socket connection = null;
DataInputStream soundIn = null;
SourceDataLine inSpeaker = null;

public SoundReceiver(Socket conn) throws Exception
{
    connection = conn;
    soundIn = new DataInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
    AudioFormat af = new AudioFormat(8000.0f,8,1,true,false);
    DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, af);
    inSpeaker = (SourceDataLine)AudioSystem.getLine(info);
    inSpeaker.open(af);
}

public void run()
{
    int bytesRead = 0;
    byte[] inSound = new byte[1];
    inSpeaker.start();
    while(bytesRead != -1)
    {
        try{bytesRead = soundIn.read(inSound, 0, inSound.length);} catch (Exception e){}
        if(bytesRead >= 0)
        {
            inSpeaker.write(inSound, 0, bytesRead);
        }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I used this program to fit into my chat application but all I hear on the receiver's end is static noise..Then I noticed the buffer size used is one byte...can this really work? I made it work changing buffer size to 1024. Also changed audio format from mono to stereo.....but can the question's configuration really transmit audio (1 byte buffer)?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the code we now check if the socket we want to send data to is the same socket that we read the data from and if so we skip it.

```
public void run()
{
    int bytesRead = 0;
    byte[] inBytes = new byte[1];
    while(bytesRead != -1)
    {
        try{bytesRead = dataIn.read(inBytes, 0, inBytes.length);}catch (IOException e)       {}
        if(bytesRead >= 0)
        {
            sendToAll(connection, inBytes, bytesRead);
        }
    }
    sockets.remove(connection);
}


public static void sendToAll(Socket connection, byte[] byteArray, int q)
{
    Iterator<socket> sockIt = sockets.iterator();
    while(sockIt.hasNext())
    {
        Socket temp = sockIt.next();
        if(connection == temp){
            continue;
        }
        DataOutputStream tempOut = null;
        try
        {
            tempOut = new DataOutputStream(temp.getOutputStream());
        } catch (IOException e1)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try{tempOut.write(byteArray, 0, q);}catch (IOException e){}
      }
  }
```

Comment: means we have to change the argument every time a new client joins the server?

Comment: no, sendAll is being called from EChoThread that has connection instance just pass this to sendAll and there compare sockIt with connection if they are the same then this is the same socket that is sending the date and there is no need to send data to it self so just skip it and move to the next socket

Comment: I am getting a bit confused. could please paste the edited program?

Comment: Also note that this piece of code sockets.remove(connection); removes the socket from the list of all sockets available so this socket won't be able to receive any audio in the future, meaning if one client send voice data it will not be able to receive any voice data later on I don't think this is what you want to happen so this line should be removed.

Comment: any ways to make the server program behave as client too. i mean the server can be also be to hear and speak to client?

Comment: well i am new and i can't vote bcz some guys negative voted on my question and my reputation decreased below 15

Comment: I used this program to fit into my chat application but all I hear on the receiver's end is static noise..